# where is the tmp data stored between pipe

Tags: linux

I just wonder where the temp data is stored during pipes.
For example, `ls -alh | grep sth`
If the ls command would generate a lot information, say bigger than 10G (of cause impossible in reality), where would this information be placed?

Comment: I'm not sure it is - the OS might block output in the ls process until grep is ready to read it, although there'll be a small (4K?) buffer in the C library at each end depending on which calls they're using. But I'm guessing.

Comment: @Rup: I don't know about the size, but conceptually you are correct. The data is stored in a kernel buffer, and `write` call made by `ls` will simply block when the buffer is full.